# Project structure in Golang and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an old project with a folder structure like this:
[image]

and the new projects folder structure:
[image]

The server.go file looks like this starting with the old project:
[image]
and the new project:
[image]

I have the same GOPATH because I'm on the same computer at this exact time.

Why can I find the handlers and types folders from the old project but not from the new? I dont know if I'm doing anything different.

I get the new project working if I import the types and handlers folder by writing:

```
import ( "domain/handlers" )
```

where domain is the domain of my project and the root folder for this new project.

I can't import this way because when I deploy to GAE the program doesnt find my static folder if server.go resides in a subfolder..

thankful for any help in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locations working for me (~/ is home folder):

~/go_appengine

~/Programming/golang_projects/bin
~/Programming/golang_projects/pkg
~/Programming/golang_projects/src

~/Programming/golang_projects/src/glassbackend/app.yaml
~/Programming/golang_projects/src/glassbackend/server.go
~/Programming/golang_projects/src/glassbackend/handlers/handler1.go
~/Programming/golang_projects/src/glassbackend/types/type1.go

In server.go:

```
import (

    "types"
    "handlers"
)
```

GOPATH = ~/Programming/golang_projects